# Alignment of text in matlab 'text' command

Tags: matlab, text, alignment

I want to print the following text on a matlab figure with ':' sign vertically aligned:

> Total Events: 1234
>   Mean Value: 1234
>   Standard Deviation: 1234
>   1st Quartile: 1234
>   ...
>   ...

I am using `text` function and trying to insert spaces manually but they never seemed to be aligned perfectly and looks wavy.

Any helps, please.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have done, the result, and why it's not what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fixed-width font and use a cell array to put the text on different lines:

```
text( 0, 0, { '      Total Events: 1234' ...
              '        Mean Value: 1234' ...
              'Standard Deviation: 1234' ...
              '      1st Quartile: 1234' }, 'FontName', 'FixedWidth' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [string format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html)

```
strings = {'Total Events', 'Mean Value', 'Standard Deviation', '1st Quartile'};
max_len = max( cellfun( @numel, strings ) );
fs = sprintf( '%% %ds: 1234\n', max_len );
cellfun( @(x) fprintf(1,fs,x), strings );
```

Results with:

```
      Total Events: 1234
        Mean Value: 1234
Standard Deviation: 1234
      1st Quartile: 1234
```

As you can see the command that aligns to the right is

```
 sprintf( '% 18s: 1234', strings{1} )
```

So, eventually in your `text` command, instead of explicitly writing a string, you can format one using `sprintf`:

```
 text( 0, 0, sprintf( '% 18s: %d', strings{ii}, values(ii) );
```

Assuming you have `strings` - cell array of strings and same-length array `values` with corresponding values to print.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was trying to show on my plot but please tell me how can I put different values in place of 1234. I used 1234 as example.

Comment: @Mushi please see my edit. please read the documentation of string formatting and `sprintf`.

Comment: Thank you very much but I like Leonard's way easy to do.